# ActionBar vs Toolbar or ActionBar and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I have read about the toolbar coming in the AppCompat Library and all its features. Some of the things I have noticed in android developers blog ([here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)) is:

> Toolbar is fully supported in AppCompat and has feature and API parity
>   with the framework widget.

They have also mentioned that we can have more control on its looks and appearance.

But, when I add an activity in Android Studio I am getting this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_add_contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here Toolbar is inside AppBar. (ActionBar and AppBar is same. Isn't it?) What is the use of that. In some blogs also I read that AppBar can be replaced with design support libraries' toolbar.

Normally you get content_layout after your Toolbar. so we will have below line after toolbar.

```
<include layout="@layout/content_myactivity" />
```

So, once I had an issue that content is above toolbar (used only toolbar, not inside appbar) hiding the whole toolbar, and still clickable. So I had to move Toolbar below my content in code to get it appeared above my content.

So, what to use? Toolbar? AppBarLayout? Toolbar inside AppBarLayout?

What is the intended use of each one?

**UPDATE**:

So I have already added Toolbar in the activity_layout file. Then why needed to use  `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` to set toolbar and adding theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. This a normal behavior with all activities in Android Studio.

What is the use of disabling window action bar with

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and setting it with `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` ?

Comment: This is one the best questions I've ever seen. Coming from more than 10 years of professional development, and working with many programming languages and frameworks, I have to say that Android's architecture and design is really a pain in the ass. Many many times I ask myself couldn't things just be easier, or more cleaner? I loved your question, because to ask "why" is a very important aspect of knowledge, that SO doesn't let happen that much.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Thank you :)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati i quite agree with you! android developing is really terrible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AppBarLayout` is a container, where you can place `ToolBar`, `TabLayout`, something else maybe. All of it will be shown on top of the screen, no matter what layout you use for the rest of the content. You can use `Toolbar` without `AppBarLayout` if you want, but then you'll need to include it in your `ViewGroup` which you use the rest of the content. And place it on the bottom of it, so it won't get overlayed with something else.

`AppBar` saves you from that and provides some additional features, for instance, scrolling behavior. It is written [here btw.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html)

Also note, that `AppBarLayout` depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a `CoordinatorLayout`. If you use `AppBarLayout` within a different `ViewGroup`, most of it's functionality will not work.

Comment: Thanks, So AppBarLayout can include all normal widgets like Relativelayout, ImageView, TextView etc?

Comment: Consider it is a vertical LinearLayout. So yes.

Answer (score 2):

AppBarLayout is a vertical `LinearLayout` which implements many of the features of material designs app bar concept, namely scrolling gestures.

Children should provide their desired scrolling behavior through `setScrollFlags(int)` and the associated layout xml attribute: app:layout_scrollFlags.

This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a `CoordinatorLayout`. If you use AppBarLayout within a different `ViewGroup`, most of it's functionality will not work.

AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to know when to scroll. The binding is done through the `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` behavior class, meaning that you should set your scrolling view's behavior to be an instance of `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`. A string resource containing the full class name is available.

You also implement like below as multiple child of `AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- Your scrolling content -->

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Source: [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html)

See also [Structure of AppBarLayout](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

Comment: This is the exact copy from the android developer site

Comment: Yes. I already given reference in my answer. I put code and description in my answer which will helps in case of main link content will changed or may removed.